# Lock File in shared location

Tags: c#, io, locking

we have C# windows application. it is used by so many users parallel. the application uses one xml file from shared location(server). and this application uses this file in many methods.

My question is IF one user start using this file, then if any other user try to use same file it should show message to user saying the file using by some one try after some time.

Note : If i am using in one method i can say Using(Filestream ..........) but i am using in multiple methods.

Comment: A bad idea : If a user starts using the file ,rename it (Ex : sample.xml.loc) .If the file name ends with .loc others should wait. If the first users completes his works  rename it back (to sample.xml).Then the file will be available for all.

Comment: If the file is not stored on the computer running the application, I don't think you can expect to be able to safely lock it. IIRC, the SQLite developer had encountered this issue aswell.

Comment: When UserA is using the file, is he modifying it ?

Comment: @Pravprab: What if user not has write permission to change filename. If is is read only ?

Comment: If the file is read-only, why do you need to lock it ?

Comment: @LucMorin : yes he is modifying. Thats the reason planning to lock till he closes the project.

Comment: Some user has write permission and some will not.

Comment: @Vasanth In the case of a user without  write permission , you dont need to lock the file, as without  write permission he is not going to modify the file. right ?

Comment: @pravprab Some user has write permission... and some user will not have write permission. We should consider for both users.

Comment: I'd just like to add that I don't find this a good idea. What if a user starts the application, opening this file, then leaves it opened for some period of time ? The other users can't work then ? I think such global settings should better be stored in a database.

Comment: We are not using the database in our project. We are just using the xml file from starting of project to close the project. if other user can't work also it is fine. He will wait till the user closes the project.